# How to fade a background color using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Currently everyone talks of two solutions:

1. jQuery UI plugin --> not feasible, because it uses too much space
2. jQuery Color (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) --> not feasible because I can't actually get a link to the plugin to download

So my question is, what is the smallest plugin I can use to allow this effect with jQuery v1.7.2?

Comment: Are you just fading something in or out, or are you fading between two colors, which of course would require a plugin or hooking onto the step method of animate()

Comment: I am fading from GREEN to transparent in 3 seconds?

Comment: Fading to transparent would be the same as just fading the element out with opacity, which don't require a plugin at all -> [**See FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/784Wb/)

Comment: @adeno It's not the same.. Opacity 0 hides the element and **all elements inside it**.. Transparent background is another thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [`jQuery Color`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) plugin from its GitHub repository.

```
span.value {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```
$("span.value").animate({
  backgroundColor: "transparent"
}, 'slow');
```

[See a live example using jQuery Color.](http://jsfiddle.net/KVFZM/)

---

You can also make use of [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

```
span.value {
  background-color: #0f0;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.fade {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```
$("span.value").toggleClass("fade");
```

[See a live example using CSS· transitions.](http://jsfiddle.net/KVFZM/)

Comment: $("span.value").animate({backgroundColor: '#00FF00'}) --> this doesn't fade from one to the other, but rather just changes the color. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RD., There's no way to know without some context. You could check the example I just posted

Comment: You're missing the speed -> `$("span.value").animate({backgroundColor: '#00FF00'}, 3000);`

Answer (score 2):

You could, if you ultimately choose not to use the jQuery color plugin, use CSS transitions:

```
<button id="fadeTrigger">fade with jQuery <span>(and CSS...)</span></button>

<div id="target" class="base">
    <p>some text in the targetted div element</p>
</div>​
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#fadeTrigger').click(
    function(){
        $('#target').toggleClass('base highlighted');
    });​
```

And CSS:

```
button {
    font-size: 1em;
}

button span {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-style: italic;
}

#target.base {
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

#target.highlighted {
    background-color: #f90;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tMpvJ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I never try but ou can maybe animate with a rgba

rgba(0, 255, 0, 1) => rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)

Comment: maybe not with query but with a setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by animate  try

```
 $('span').animate({'backgroundColor' : '#ffff99'});
```

or try

```
 $("span").fadeOut("slow").css("background-color", "#ffff99");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use those plugins with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
```

in your `head` tags rather than having to download them.

try

```
 $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#HEXCODE' }, 'fast');
```

Or, you could use `opacity` property in CSS on hover.

```
 #id{
   opacity:1;
  }

 #id:hover{
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think you really understand how it works. The user would still have to download the scripts, regardless if they have been linked to on your own server or on somone else's server.

Comment: I didn't say the user wouldn't be downloading them. I said @RD. wouldn't need to download them and link from his server.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a really simple jQuery plugin to fade colors. It could use a little polishing, but I think it's what you're after. You can check it out here: https://gist.github.com/4569265